# Why is python's dict implemented as hash table whereas std::map is tree-based?

Tags: c++, python, dictionary, hashtable

Why one languages uses tree and another uses hash table for seemingly similar data structure?

c++'s map vs python's dict

A related question is about performance of hash table.
Please comment on my understanding of hash table below.

A tree is guaranteed to have O(log n).
Whereas hash table has no guarantee unless inputs are previously known because of possible collisions.
I tend to think hash table's performance would become close to O(n) as problem size gets bigger.
Because I haven't heard of a hash function that dynamically adjust its table size as problem size grows.

Hence, hash table is only useful for certain range of problem size, and that's why most DB uses tree than hash table.

Comment: and Haskell Data.Map which is based on size balanced binary trees

Comment: Usually the hash you use is many times larger than the table size, so you can resize the table and just use a different modulus. The reason why databases use trees (different trees, too) is minimizing disk accesses and keeping much of the actual structure in memory so you can get directly to the data without too many wasteful head movements (moot with SSDs, but still, cutting down disk access is a major factor).

Comment: @Joey: So, hash table is rather hard to operate in memory when size are big. On the other hand, tree is naturally suitable in that regard. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: trees could work at O(n) in the special case when an unbalanced tree becomes a list. in order to make tree balanced and working O(lon n) one has to spend some time for balancing it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The new C++ standard has the `std::unordered_map` type [which is a hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_%28C++%29). IIRC they wanted it to get into the previous standard as well, but there was not enough time during the discussions so it was left out. However, most popular compilers provided it in one way or another for years.

In other words, don't worry about it too much. Use the proper data structure for the task at hand.

---

As for your understanding of hash tables, it's inaccurate:

> I haven't heard of a hash function that dynamically adjust its table
>   size as problem size grows

All serious hash table implementation dynamically adjust themselves for growing input, by allocating a larger array and re-hashing all the keys. Although this operation is expensive, if designed properly (to be done rarely enough) the performance is still amortized O(1).

Answer (score 13):

Your understanding of hash tables (and who use them) is flawed.

The problem is, hash table is a rather vague term. Under the hood there are many implementations... but first let's talk about the use of BST (Binary Search Trees).

---

> Why does C++ uses a Binary Search Tree ?

<strike>C++ is designed by commitee, there are many possible implementations of hash tables leading to widely different characteristics while the most popular implementations of BST (Red-Black Tree and AVL Tree) have nearly identical characteristics. Therefore, they did not rejected hash tables outright, they just could not settle on the characteristics to choose and the details to expose to the user.</strike>

See James Kanze's comment, the proposal arrived too late and James asks an interesting question as to why Stepanov did not proposed it first. I still suspect the number of choices to be the culprit.

> Why do databases use Search Trees ?

First of all, let's settle on a database software. I'll pick Oracle because it's both widely documented and so typical of SQL databases. Oracle offers two types of indexes: Bitmap and Search Trees.

*Note: they do not use BINARY Search Trees, but instead use B+Trees which are much more IO and cache friendly*

There is a fundamental difference between a Hash Table and a Search Tree: the latter is sorted. Many databases operations imply sorting:

- get the nth element
- get the top n elements
- get the elements in [a,b]

In all those cases, a Hash Table is useless.

Furthermore, databases need to juggle with huge datasets (in general), which means that they need to organize their data in order to minimize IO (disk read/write). Here, the sorted nature of a Search Tree mean that (in the index) elements that are likely to be accessed together (because they share much) will also be grouped together instead of being scattered to the four corners of the disk.

Finally, *internally* Oracle may use Hash Tables in its execution plan. When you perform an operation that requires the intersection of two sets of rows, the optimization engine may decide that storing the (temporary) sets in Hash Tables is the fastest way to go.

---

Now, regarding performance.

Indeed, the performance of Search Trees is generally well-known and easy to understand O(log N) is nice and tidy.

On the other hand, as I said, there are many different Hash Tables implementation possible, as well as strategies to handle both growth and shrink... definitely more complicated.

A simple example of structure, a Hash Table may use:

- Open Addressing: the hash table is an array of elements, the hash indicates the slot of the array in which to put the element, if the slot is full there is a strategy to locate another slot. The same strategy is used for searching.
- Buckets: the hash table is an array of pointers to buckets, the hash indicates the slot of the bucket in which to put the elements. It is assumed that the bucket can grow infinitely.

Those two strategies have extremely different characteristics, and the latter characteristics also depend on the buckets implementations (the easy implementation is to use a simple linked-list).

But even if you pick an implementation, its performance is based on the hash function distribution, which varies depending on the input sequence itself!

---

My personal advice ? To pick between `unordered_map` and `map` in C++, I simply ask myself about whether I need sorted elements or not. If I need them to be sorted I use a `map`, otherwise I use an `unordered_map`. Most of the times, the performances are just as good anyway, so it's just **semantics**.

Comment: nice answer, but why the last sentence? I found `unordered_map` to be significantly faster than `map` for the typical lookup-needs (no sorting required) in large data sets

Comment: @EliBendersky: Because most beginners are too drawn to performance, they focus on big O while they use sequences of 10 elements... If you need performance, measure (profile), otherwise just make your life easier by picking a container that supports the semantics you need for the task at hand.

Comment: fair enough, but I think an SO answer should be made accurate in the general sense, and not aimed at a specific segment of users (beginners who don't understand performance and big-O stuff). If you do aim it at a segment, at least note it explicitly in parentheses or a footnote. Otherwise, taken out of its context the answer just doesn't appear right

Comment: Some points of history: most of C++ was not designed by a committee; for 
the most part (there are exceptions) the committee standardized existing
practice.  Much of the library comes from the Alexander Stepanov's STL,
so the question is why Stepanov chose a binary tree rather than a hash
table.  And why no one presented a proposal for a hash table until it
was too late---when the proposal was presented, the committee looked on
it very favorably, but rejected it because it was too late in the
process to integrate something that new into the standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Rereading my answer it's unclear that it was a suspicion of mine. I've striked it all and redirected to your comment.

Comment: "get the nth element, get the top n elements, get the elements in [a,b] " +1 for educating a newb!

Answer (score 5):

It's a more or less arbitrary choice of the language designers.  In the
case of C++, I suspect (but don't know for sure) that the motivation was
the desire to define strict upper limits to complexity: designing a good
hash function isn't trivial, and a hash table with a poor hash function
performs very poorly.  Another issue that might have been considered is
the fact that there is an established operator for ordering (`<`); there
is nothing similar for hashing.

In the case of Python (and many other languages), a lot of the time, the
keys will be a built-in type, like `str` (`std::string` was not 
available when the STL was being defined), so you can ensure an adequate
hash function.  And when everything is an object, and inherits from a
common base class, you can easily define a standard interface for
`hash`, by defining a (virtual) function in the univeral base class.

Finally, the C++ solution depends on a single function/operator; a hash
table requires two (the hash function and equality), which must
compatible, which is more error prone.  A common error in Java is to
define `equals`, but not to define `hashCode`; I suspect that there are
Python classes which make the same mistake (defining `__cmp__` or
`__eq__`, but not `__hash__`).  Of course, seeing the number of times
people mess up the `<` operator in C++, I'm not sure that it's that safe
either:-).

Answer (score 4):

Python hash tables are never more than 2/3 full.  The resize as they grow (starting at size 8, then quadrupling in size to until 50000, and doubling thereafter).  This gives them amortized O(1) insertion, deletion, and lookup.  Excess collisions are possible but are rare.